# absolutely continuous measure from $L^{1}$ function.

Tags: measure-theory

I am having difficulty clearly understanding some concepts in measures. Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that the derivative  $f' \in L^1([a,b])$ and $$f(x)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)\,dt \quad(a\le x \le b).$$It is stated in measure theory  text that these two conditions imply the existence of a measure $\mu$, defined by $d\mu=f'dm$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.  From a previous theorem one can see that $f'_{+}dm$ and $f'_{-}dm$ are both positive measures, where $f'_{+}$ and $f'_{-}$ are the positive and negative parts of the function $f'$. But for existence of these measures, one only needs $f'$ to be measurable. Does the existence of the above integral only ensures that $\mu$ is a signed measure? Also, if one writes $$d\mu=f'_{+}dm-f'_{-}dm,$$does this give a Hahn decomposition of the signed measure $\mu$?

Thanks.

Comment: Before you can define $d\mu=f'_{+}dm-f'_{-}dm$ you need  to be certain it's not going to lead to $\mu(E)=\infty-\infty$.